# mysql: why below query unused union index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

```
table a
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| uid      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| channel  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createAt | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

table a index: a_index_uid_createAt` (`uid`,`createAt`)


table b:
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| date      | date        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| channel   | varchar(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| gender    | smallint(6) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| chargeAmt | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| revised   | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| createAt  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

query st:

```
select  DATE(a.createAt) date,a.channel,b.chargeAmt
    FROM  a, b
    where  a.uid = b.uid
      and  a.createAt >= '2021-05-10 00:00:00'
      and  a.createAt <= '2021-05-10 23:59:59';
```

explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                   | key     | key_len | ref          | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL    | a_index_uid_createAt | NULL    | NULL    | NULL         | 172725 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY | 4       | xiehou.r.uid |      1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------+--------+-------------+
```

why? a_index_uid_createAt index invalid!

Comment: createAt doesn't seem to think it's part of a composite key

Comment: yes. but why , how fixed it , create a single createAt index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `JOIN .. ON` syntax:

```
select  DATE(a.createAt) date, a.channel, b.chargeAmt
    FROM  a
    JOIN  b  ON  a.uid = b.uid   -- How the tables are related
    WHERE  a.createAt >= '2021-05-10                    -- filtering
      and  a.createAt  < '2021-05-10 + INTERVAL 1 DAY;  -- filtering
```

The Optimizer, when it sees a `JOIN`, starts by deciding which table to start with.  The preferred table is the one with filtering, namely `a`.

To do the filtering, it needs an index that *starts* with the columns mentioned in the `WHERE` clause.

The other table will be reached by looking at the `ON`, which seems to have `PRIMARY KEY(uid)`

So, the only useful index is

```
a:  INDEX(createAt)
```

Any `INDEX(uid, ...)` is likely to be unused, since it starts with an existing index, namely `PRIMARY KEY(uid)`.

(In the future, please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.)